# Baidu trying to access .ftpquota in Nginx access.log

Tags: nginx, ftp, log-files

When I look at the Nginx access.log there are always several attempts from Baidu to access the file .ftpquota.

When I do a `ls -a` I can see that the file even doesn't exist. I don't use FTP.

Here are some logs:

```
180.76.6.28 - - [11/Apr/2015:13:01:06 -0300] "GET /.ftpquota HTTP/1.1" 404 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.6.20 - - [11/Apr/2015:14:04:46 -0300] "GET /.ftpquota HTTP/1.1" 404 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.6.135 - - [11/Apr/2015:14:19:57 -0300] "GET /.ftpquota HTTP/1.1" 404 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.5.194 - - [11/Apr/2015:17:30:46 -0300] "GET /.ftpquota HTTP/1.1" 404 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.6.47 - - [11/Apr/2015:19:15:49 -0300] "GET /.ftpquota HTTP/1.1" 404 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.5.166 - - [11/Apr/2015:19:40:24 -0300] "GET /.ftpquota HTTP/1.1" 404 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.5.75 - - [11/Apr/2015:22:56:25 -0300] "GET /.ftpquota HTTP/1.1" 404 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.5.58 - - [11/Apr/2015:23:50:22 -0300] "GET /.ftpquota HTTP/1.1" 404 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.5.57 - - [12/Apr/2015:02:56:14 -0300] "GET /.ftpquota HTTP/1.1" 404 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.5.152 - - [12/Apr/2015:03:02:38 -0300] "GET /.ftpquota HTTP/1.1" 404 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.5.168 - - [12/Apr/2015:03:28:41 -0300] "GET /.ftpquota HTTP/1.1" 404 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.5.150 - - [12/Apr/2015:03:31:32 -0300] "GET /.ftpquota HTTP/1.1" 404 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
123.125.71.112 - - [12/Apr/2015:03:45:20 -0300] "GET /.ftpquota HTTP/1.1" 404 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
180.76.6.42 - - [12/Apr/2015:04:52:53 -0300] "GET /.ftpquota HTTP/1.1" 404 322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
```

**Why do Baido keep trying to access .ftpquota if it doesn't exist? Is it some kind of malicious attempt?**

Comment: Maybe the previous owner of the domain name had such a file.

Comment: ProFTPD *used* to have a module called `mod_quota`, written by Eric Estabrook.  (The `mod_quota` module was not maintained, and was replaced by [`mod_quotatab`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_quotatab.html).)  This old `mod_quota` module would track per-user quota in a file called `.ftpquota`.  Perhaps the Baidu software used to operate/interact/use this file, when present?